# How automatic status change works in Salesforce Field Service lightning Mobile App?

Tags: salesforce

We have done the setup for automatic status change feature referring this article : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_automatic_status_change_beta_settings.htm&type=5

We are struggling with the testing of this feature as to how the updates are triggered, no message is visible on mobile app.

We have scheduled the service appointment providing appropriate time slot and also the address nearby to the mobile app user location but no message is coming up on mobile app.

Any help on testing automatic status change in Field service app will be really appreciated.